# How to calculate the no. of Weeks from present week to given week?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, time-series

I have a column present in the format "YYYY-WW" which contains a future week. How to calculate the no. of weeks from present week till this future week in Python ?

Comment: So the date data are strings?  Is `2021-40` the 40th week in 2021?  There's not enough information here.

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow. On this site, you should first provide your solution and ask why does it not work.

Comment: please have another read of [ask] and provide a [mre] alongside your attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new column to convert the "YYYY-WW" format to Monday's date of week like so:

```
df.MondayDate = pd.to_datetime(df['YYYY-WW'] + '-1', format='%Y-%W-%w')
```

Then you can use this newly created column to calculate the difference in days and convert to week like:

```
df.WeeksRemaining = (df['MondayDate']-pd.Timestamp.today())/np.timedelta64(1, 'W')
```